# O lies in the Gauss line

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Given a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ inscribed $(O)$. The internal bisectors of the angles $A,B,C,D$ meet each others to form a quadrilateral $XYZT$. Prove $O$ lies in the Gauss-Newton line of $XYZT$
[image]

Comment: The conclusion still true with the external bisectors

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @greenturtle3141: I get it from AOPS

Comment: I think the AOPS forums is a much better place to ask this if you want answers.